# Number of ways to merge 2 parenthesis sequences?

Tags: string, dynamic-programming, parentheses

You are given two strings `s` and `t` which consist of `(` and `)` and are not necessarily balanced.

Print the number of ways to interleave these two strings to produce a balanced parenthesis expression.

E.g. `((` and `))` can be combined in two ways to produce `()()` and `(())`

I know a solution using dynamic programming that works in `O(nm * min(n,m))` where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the two strings. The state is `dp[i][j][k]` - number of strings that you can make using the first `i` characters of `s`, the first `j` characters of `t` with `k` number of unmatched opening parenthesis.

Can this same problem be solved in `O(nm)` time?

Comment: Is the goal to print all possible valid interleaves, the number of all possible valid interleaves, or just any valid interleave within O(n*m)?

Comment: I suppose that `s+t` has same number of opening and closing paranthesis. Your approach needs `k=(n+m)/2`. And `dp` element can have special value for not possible situation like `s=t=)(`.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in O(n*m) time, since none of the states can be eliminated

Comment: @Assafs the goal is to count the number of possible valid interleaves. No printing is required.

Comment: @marvel308 Yes I don't see any way to eliminate states from my formulation of the dp states either, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you cannot formulate the problem in another way :)